# rails view performance: default rendering vs cached rendering?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

With a haml template:

```
  .row
    .col-12
      .discount-notice
        %ul
          %li= t(".info").html_safe
          %li= t(".stuff").html_safe
          %li= t(".discount").html_safe
          %li= t(".cheese").html_safe
          %li= t(".fire-sale").html_safe
```

**Is It more performant** to let haml/rails render this as is or to wrap in a `cache` block and fetch from memcached?